# Apply command to every table on sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This code selects all cells with a specific color.

```vb
Sub Validation()
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim FoundRange As Range
Set rng = Range("L54:L4000")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
        If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            Set FoundRange = cell
        Else
            Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then FoundRange.Select
End sub
```

It works on simple sheets, but I have a sheet full of tables I need it to work on as well. At the moment it only selects the cells on the first sheet.

I tried to apply it to each table:

```vb
Sub Validation()
Dim co As ListObject
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim FoundRange As Range
Set rng = Range("L54:L4000")
For Each co In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                Set FoundRange = cell
            Else
                Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then FoundRange.Select
Next co
End sub
```

The first code applied *for each* cell and I wanted to treat it as an "integer" and apply it *for each* table.

Comment: You say you have a sheet full of tables you need it to work on, but you also say it only works on the first sheet.  Is it 1 sheet with many tables (@FaneDuru answer will work) or many sheets with many tables - you can't have a union of ranges across different sheets.  So you'll have to select cells on first sheet, move to second sheet and select cells on there.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a range, `rng` which has nothing to to with the iterated listObjects...

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub Validation()
 Dim co As ListObject, cell As Range
 Dim rng As Range, FoundRange As Range

 For Each co In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    Set rng = co.DataBodyRange 'supposing that you want searching in the table dataBodyRange. 
                               'if you need to do it in the whole table (headers included), you should use co.Range
    For Each cell In rng.cells
        If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                Set FoundRange = cell
            Else
                Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, cell)
             End If
        End If
    Next cell
  Next co
  If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then FoundRange.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean tables on different sheets then this code would work.
If it's actual tables you're searching change the `rng` to look at each `ListObject` in `wrkSht.ListObjects` as shown in the answer given by @FaneDuru.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        wrkSht.Select 'First time I've used Select in about 10 years.
    
        Set FoundRange = Nothing
        Set rng = wrkSht.Range("L54:L4000")
        
        For Each Cell In rng.Cells
            If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
                If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set FoundRange = Cell
                Else
                    Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, Cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
        
        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            FoundRange.Select 'Second time.....
        End If
        
    Next wrkSht
    
End Sub
```